# Double click document

Tags: javascript

Getting double click instead of single click

```
var element = document.getElementById('callModal')
element.addEventListener("click", (e:any) => this.test(e));
```

How to prevent this ?

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 831, screenY: 275, clientX: 766, clientY: 185…}
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 831, screenY: 275, clientX: 766, clientY: 185…}
```

Comment: How to prevent what? People from clicking twice? Or are you saying that with a single click, two logs appear? If that's the case, then most likely you bound the handler twice.

Comment: yep 
two logs appear

Comment: Then you've bound it twice. You just need to figure out where.

Comment: Are you using a specific framework or precompiler? `e:any` is not a standard event

Comment: react with typescript

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the double-click event instead.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp

Comment: don't help 

When i click on that container i'm getting for exmaple two lines of ``console.log('test')`` -> in my console will show ( test,test ) multiple